# LM1881 noise at CSync output when not connected to anything

Tags: analog, video

Im trying to get CSync and VSync out of an composite video signal. This is my schematic:

[image]

It's the same circuit as in the documention of the [LM1881](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm1881). In general it works well, but I noticed something: if the device where the composite video comes from is turned off, there is a little noise before the capacitor C1. This was enough to trigger the LM1881. I fixed it by adding a 50 kΩ resistor to ground before C1.

[image]

Next I discovered that when I remove the plug where the composite video is coming from, the LM1881 picks up more noise. Adding a resistor to ground after C1 didn't work since it started to shift the CSync signal. Is there anything I can do?

Measurements without the 50 kΩ resistor:

Connected and device on:
[image]

Connected but device off:
[image]

Disconnected:
[image]

Comment: Does that 50K-to-GND *really* connect to "RCA composite video"? That RCA input *should* be terminated with a 75 ohm resistance somewhere nearby. If so, you should be able to decrease 50Kohm considerably before it loads-down the composite video.

Comment: Is the composite video going somewhere else too, or should it be terminated by this circuit? There are no optional filter components either. The chip has also no bypass caps, or at least not drawn.

Comment: this it the complete circuit. Composite Video comes straight from my source device (PS1).   But getting a clean csync signal is not the problem. The problem is if the device is not running / not connected to this circuit the LM1881 picks up noise and floods the Csync signal

Comment: As already mentioned, your 50Kohm should be 75ohm. It is not shown in the datasheet application circuit because terminating an analog video line is a basic concept assumed by the authors. There are rare cases where you should not terminate, but if you're solely driving composite from a PlayStation you should definitely terminate with 75ohm. Not only will it help resolve your problem, but without it you're likely slicing the sync at a non-optimal level which can cause instability and jitter on the CSYNC output pulses edges. Lastly, check section 9 of the datasheet...you're missing a component.

Comment: Yes you are correct im should replace the 50kohm with 75 ohm resistors. An on the missing component i have a 0.1uF cap on pin 8 but i didn't draw it in the schematic

Answer (score 1):

As Ste Kulov mentioned, I needed to terminate the line currently with a 75R resistor.